# AWS EC2 & EBS for personal development server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'm AWS free-tier user and planning to Use AWS EC2 & EBS as a personal web development server. I will be using this machine 100 hours max in a month. Will be stopping and starting the EC2 instance. What will be the best configuration for EC2/EBS for running development ENV for good performance? Would I be able changes EC2 instance after setup?

Development Environment

- Ubuntu
- Ruby
- Python
- Nodejs
- Docker
- Kubernetes
- Vscode
- database server
- Remote Desktop Client -> VNC

**EC2 Instance**

[image: Amazon EC2 A1 instances]
[image: T3 instances]
[image: T3a instances]
[image: T2 instances]
**EBS Volume**

- General Purpose SSD (gp2)
- Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1)
- Throughput Optimized HDD (st1)
- Cold HDD (sc1)

Answer (score 1):

Start with a t3.micro and GP2. Then once you're using it you can stop the instance and change instance type as demand requires.